# Is there a way to add the attribute loading="lazy" only in certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading

I am using the [relativly new HTML attribute loading="lazy"](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/). I only want it to be enabled when the number of images rendered on the page excedes 10. I am building my website using Vue.js v3. I am loading the images with a v-for card like this:

```
    <div
      class="gallery-panel"
      v-for="photo in filteredPhotos"
      v-bind:key="photo.id"
      :class="`${photo.display}`"
    >
      <a @click="this.$router.push(`/Album/${album}/Photo/${photo.id}`)">
        <img
          loading="auto"
          v-bind:src="thumbUrl(photo.filename, album)"
          v-bind:alt="`${photo.filename}`"
        />
      </a>
    </div>
```

Where filteredPhotos is an array with image information from a JSON file.

Is there a way to change the loading="auto" to loading="lazy" when the number of photos is going to be more than 10?

Comment: `:loading="filteredPhotos.length > 10 ? 'lazy' : 'auto'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simply add an `index` attribute to your `v-for` to check whether the length of your array exceeding 10 or not *(Since the index will begin from 0 you should set your condition to `> 9`)*. Then you can make your `loading` attribute conditional like this:

```html
<img :loading="index > 9 ? 'lazy' : 'auto'" />
```

So your final code should be something like this:

```html
<div class="gallery-panel" v-for="(photo, index) in filteredPhotos" v-bind:key="photo.id" :class="`${photo.display}`">
  <a @click="this.$router.push(`/Album/${album}/Photo/${photo.id}`)">
    <img :loading="index > 9 ? 'lazy' : 'auto'" v-bind:src="thumbUrl(photo.filename, album)" v-bind:alt="`${photo.filename}`" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` of `v-for` e.g

```
<div
  class="gallery-panel"
  v-for="(photo, index) in filteredPhotos"
  v-bind:key="photo.id"
  :class="`${photo.display}`"
>
  <a @click="this.$router.push(`/Album/${album}/Photo/${photo.id}`)">
    <img
      :loading="index > 9 ? 'lazy' : 'auto'"
      v-bind:src="thumbUrl(photo.filename, album)"
      v-bind:alt="`${photo.filename}`"
    />
  </a>
</div>
```